# xUnit Mock request new instance from IoC container

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I am writing some unit tests for a method that uploads a file using SSH.Net.

The project is a WPF app and uses Caliburn.Micro as MVVM framework and also to inject the following object in the constructor of the class I am testing:

```
    private IFileTransferManager _fileTransferManager;

    public FileUploadViewModel(IFileTransferManager fileTransferManager) : base(eventAggregator)
    {
        _fileTransferManager = fileTransferManager;
    }
```

In the test project I am mocking IFileTransferManager:

```
    private Mock<IFileTransferManager> _fileTransferManager = new Mock<IFileTransferManager>();
```

But now I got to the point, when in code I need to ask for a new instance of IFileTransferManager from IoC container, IoC being a static class in Caliburn.Micro:

```
    _fileTransferManager = IoC.Get<IFileTransferManager>();

    await _fileTransferManager.UploadFile(connection, file.FullName, destinationPath).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

How can I refactor the above code to make it testable, because currently it throws `System.InvalidOperationException` in Caliburn.Micro.dll due to the fact that I am re-instantiating `_fileTransferManager`?

Comment: Inject a factory using a Func delegate. I am curious though about why you would need a new instance if one is already being injected via constructor?

Comment: Ideally you should never have to directly call your IoC container like this.  If the class had an `IFileTransferManager` injected into the constructor then you wouldn't have to worry about it, because when instantiating the class for testing you'd just directly pass it your mock.

Comment: @Nkosi This question is related to another one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57902034/progress-bar-for-parallel-file-upload-with-ssh-net-and-wpf-mvvm

I am also using a progress bar to track the upload progress but if I do multiple uploads in the same time, the progress bar it is not working properly. The workaround I found is to request a new IFileTransferManager for every file I am uploading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do something like this, assuming there are other limiting factors that mean you want to change as little outward detail about the class as possible (note: I haven't tested this so may have to tweak a little)

```
public class ClassIAmTesting
{
    //Have a Func to fetch a file manager...
    private Func<IFileTransferManager> _filemgr = null;
    //Have a property which we'll use in this class to get the File manager
    public Func<IFilterTransferManager> GetFileManager
    {
        get
        {
            //If we try to use this property for the first time and it's not set,
            //then set it to the default implementation.
            if (_fileMgr == null)
            {
                _fileMgr = () => IoC.Get<IFileTransferManager>();
            }
            return _fileMgr;
        }
        set
        {         
            //allow setting of the function which returns an IFileTransferManager
            if (_fileMgr == null)
            {
                _fileMgr = value;
            }
        }
    }

    //this is the method you ultimately want to test...
    public async Task<bool> SomeMethodIAmTesting()
    {
        //don't do this any more:
        //_fileTransferManager = IoC.Get<IFileTransferManager>();

        //instead do this.
        _fileTransferManager = GetFileManager();

        await _fileTransferManager
            .UploadFile(connection, file.FullName, destinationPath)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then in your testing:

```
Mock<IFileTransferManager> _fileTransferManager = new Mock<IFileTransferManager>();
var cut = new ClassIAmTesting();
//not used Moq for a long time, but think you have to access .Object to get to the 
//actual implementation of IFileTransferManager?
cut.GetFileManager = () => _fileTransferManager.Object; 

//Do actual tests..
var result = cut.SomeMethodIAmTesting();

//Do assertions...
```

I suggest this approach because:

- It provides a way of overriding the way the class gets the `IFileTransferManager` for testing
- It 'falls back' to the default implementation if this override is not used, preserving the original behaviour - you don't need to change existing calls to this class at all from non-testing code
- It does not change the Constructor or add a new one, which I *assume* is a problem since you don't simply inject an instance of the IFileTransferManager in.

one improvement might be to make the set `internal` which would prevent other projects from setting this method, and it could then be exposed via `InternalVisibleTo` or similar, but I'm trying to keep the scope fairly tight...

Comment: You're welcome, though i should point out that this does mean your class has a non-obvious dependency on IFileTransferManager when used; you'd probably be better off in the long term injecting it directly via the constructor, then you can directly use your mock when instantiating the class for testing. Sometimes though in the real world we have to make do with solutions that work rather than ones which are also elegant

Answer (score 0):

Inject a factory using a `Func<TResult>` delegate.

```
private readonly Func<IFileTransferManager> fileTransferManagerFactory;

public FileUploadViewModel(Func<IFileTransferManager> fileTransferManagerFactory) : base(eventAggregator) {
    this.fileTransferManagerFactory = fileTransferManagerFactory;
}
```

This would allow for as many instances as needed being created when uploading

```
//get an instance using factory delegate
var fileTransferManager =  fileTransferManagerFactory();

await fileTransferManager.UploadFile(connection, file.FullName, destinationPath).ConfigureAwait(false); IoC.Get<IFileTransferManager>();
```

For unit testing a function can be easily created to provid as many mocks needed for the test case